# If densities converge then the corresponding RV converge in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I tried to prove the following

> *Theorem*: Given $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ iid. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]<\infty$. If the rv's have respective densities $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, it follows that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X$, meaning convergence in distribution.

*Proof*:
$$|F_n(x)-F(x)|\le \left | \int_{(-\infty, x]}f_n(t)\,\mathrm{d}t - \int_{(-\infty, x]}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right |\\
\le \int_{(-\infty, x]}|f_n(t)-f(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t\le \int_\mathbb{R}|f_n(t)-f(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Now because of [Scheffés-Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma) I know that the rhs. converges to zero.

Is my proof correct? I did not use the finite variance which gives me doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply Scheffé's lemma, you must prove that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n \to \int_{\mathbb{R}} f$$

However, your proof doesn't show why this should be the case.

Comment: I just noticed that I used another version of the Scheffè-Lemma which assume just pointwise convergence. But I try to show it for this version as an exercise. Do you have a hint on how show it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's even true. I just wrote where your proof fails. You also have an independency condition which you might want to use.

Comment: The hypothesis seems so that you can apply strong law of large numbers, but I don't know if that's useful.